# Following SQL query returns resultset for only available months, how to get all month if data is not present?

Tags: mysql

Following query gives result-set for available months only , how can i get for all the months if data is not present .

Eg:-
 Apr-2013 and May-2013 having the value but June-2013 no value how can i get June-2013 in result set as total is 0 .

```
SELECT CONCAT(substr(MonthName(fileddate) , 1, 3) , "-", Year(fileddate)) AS MONTH,
       count(*)
FROM carstore
WHERE store=20
  AND (soldstate = 2
       OR soldstate = 3)
  AND cartype LIKE '%Toyoto%'
  AND fileddate BETWEEN DATE('2013-04-07') AND DATE('2014-04-30')
GROUP BY MONTH
ORDER BY Year(fileddate),
         MONTH(fileddate) ;


+----------+----------+
| Month    | count(*) |
+----------+----------+
| Apr-2013 |        2 |
| May-2013 |        2 |
| Jul-2013 |       14 |
| Aug-2013 |        3 |
| Sep-2013 |        2 |
| Nov-2013 |        4 |
| Dec-2013 |       19 |
| Jan-2014 |       61 |
| Feb-2014 |       21 |
| Apr-2014 |        3 |
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the proper formation .

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array). Also, see DATE_FORMAT

Comment: Can you post your table strucure

Comment: You will need to make a MonthYear table and LEFT JOIN with carstore.

Comment: Actually carstore is a single table how can i do for left outer join